# Simplify a series involving binomial coefficients

Tags: probability, combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

For $n=2,3,\dots$ and $k=1,2,\dots,n$, I would like to prove that
$$
\sum_{\ell=k+1}^{n}\frac{2^{2\ell}}{\ell}{2n-2\ell\choose n-\ell}\left(1+\frac{2n-2\ell+1}{\ell-1}\right)=\frac{2^{2k}(2n-2k+1){2n-2k\choose n-k}}{k}.
$$

I have checked it for small $n$ and $k$. However, I am unable to come up with a method to prove it. I am wondering if it is possible to (simplify) deal with
$$
\sum_{\ell=k+1}^{n}\frac{2^{2\ell}}{\ell}{2n-2\ell\choose n-\ell}.
$$

I would be appreciate it if someone could give me some help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did your small $n,k$ check give any indication that induction could work?

Comment: Do you mean induction on $n$? I will give it a try. Thanks

Comment: But I still hope that there is a way to simplify $\sum_{\ell=k+1}^{n}\frac{2^{2\ell}}{\ell}{2n-2\ell\choose n-\ell}$. Or, to find a combinatoric identity related to it.

Comment: $\sum_{\ell=k+1}^{n}2^{2\ell}{2n-2\ell\choose n-\ell}$ has a closed form, but I doubt you'll find one with the $\ell$ in the denominator. Wolfram|Alpha just outputs a hypergeometric series, and it's usually very good at these things.

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you please tell me where I can find the closed form? I mean the closed form of $\sum_{\ell=k+1}^{n}2^{2\ell}{2n-2\ell\choose n-\ell}$.

Comment: Could you please tell me where I can find the closed form of $\sum_{\ell=k+1}^{n}2^{2\ell}{2n-2\ell\choose n-\ell}$?